# How to prevent crash from ucrtbase.dll when running .exe file in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

When a PC runs my .exe file on windows, it crashes in ucrtbase.dll as follows:

```
extern "C" LONG WINAPI __scrt_unhandled_exception_filter(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS const pointers)
{
    auto const exception_record = reinterpret_cast<EHExceptionRecord*>(pointers->ExceptionRecord);
    if (PER_IS_MSVC_PURE_OR_NATIVE_EH(exception_record))
    {
        terminate(); // Crash here
    }

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}
```

The problem is that the crash happens when my app invokes the function of a library (DLL) of a 3rd party, so I cannot control this.

Currently, is there any problem with ucrtbase.dll?

How can I prevent this crash in my scope?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is an exception that no one caught. You need to go down your call stack until you reach **your** code and try to catch the exception there. You need to find your code that calls this library's code which in turn causes the exception. Can't say anything more specific without seeing the code that leads to this.